# xmltodict returns string instead of OrderedDict

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, xml-deserialization

Given this code:

```
import xmltodict

xml = xmltodict.parse('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <B id="one">
    <C id="X">1</C>
    <C id="Y">2</C>
  </B>
  <B id="two">
    <C id="Z">3</C>
  </B>
</A>
''')
for b in xml['A']['B']:
    print(b.get('@id'))
    for c in b['C']:
        print(c)
```

output is:

```
one
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'> OrderedDict([('@id', 'X'), ('#text', '1')])
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'> OrderedDict([('@id', 'Y'), ('#text', '2')])
two
<class 'str'> @id
<class 'str'> #text
```

What am I missing / misunderstanding, why the second section is represented as strings?

Comment: Yes, same issue, thank you.